# Why every point of a function where differentiation exists has only one tangent?

Tags: derivatives

Can anyone help me out?
Why every point of a function where differentiation exists has only one tangent?
I know the slope at any point of any function is defined by differentiation at that point.But there may be another straight line which touches the function at that point but slope is different from the differentiation value at that point. But this does not happen(I am not considering singular point).

Comment: How d you define "touch"?

Comment: Touch means what u r thinking.It will have one point common(let's say C) with the curve and there is an interval around that point in where the straight line has no common point other than C with the curve.

Comment: Say $f(x)=x$.  Then, in your sense,  every line of the form $y=mx$ with $m\neq 1$ touches the graph of $f(x)$ at $(0,0)$ (and, ironically, the tangent to the curve at that point does not touch the graph in your sense).

Comment: yea I am wrong..What is ur definition

Comment: You can define it as the line through the given point with slope equal to the derivative...or you can use linear approximations, as mentioned in the answer by @TedShifrin.  See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375317/in-what-sense-is-the-derivative-the-best-linear-approximation) for a nice, general discussion.

Comment: Take a look at [my answer to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784262/how-is-the-derivative-truly-literally-the-best-linear-approximation-near-a-po/1784280#1784280).  It may help you make sense of this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not just about a line *touching*. (Every line through the point touches the graph there.) It's the *best* linear approximation, in the sense that the error $f(x)-L(x)$ goes to $0$ faster than $x$ approaches $a$. (Here $L(x)$ is the linear function whose graph we're discussing.)

**EDIT**: To be more precise, if $f$ is differentiable at $x=a$, then the linear function $L(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$ is the *unique* linear function with the property that 
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-L(x)}{x-a} = 0.$$ 
Note that if we take $L(x)=f(a)+m(x-a)$, this limit becomes
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)-m(x-a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} -m = f'(a)-m,$$
and this is $0$ if and only if $m=f'(a)$.

If $f$ fails to be differentiable, this limit will *never* be 0. Try it, for example, with $f(x)=|x|$ at $x=0$. If you take a line of slope $m$ and $x>0$, this limit is $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \dfrac{x-mx}x = 1-m$, so $m$ would have to be $1$, but if $x<0$, this limit is $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \dfrac{-x-mx}x = -1-m$, so $m$ would have to be $-1$. There therefore is no tangent line at $x=0$.

Comment: NO no if differentiation exists at that point. Only one straight line would touch the curve at that point. Touch means what I have said earlier in a comment

Comment: Forgive me I want to ask you then why there is no derivative at sharp point of a curve?

Comment: @sani: See my edit. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This really just comes down to how you define the **line tangent to a curve** at a point.  Your implied definition that it is a line which "touches" the curve at the point in question but not any of its neighbors in some small interval just brings up the question, "What does 'touches' mean in this context?"  If you just mean "intersect", then your definition does not fit with modern definitions of the concept.  Which is fine, but if that's the case, then you're right that there *are* many tangent lines to most curves at most points.  And in fact a curve doesn't even need to be differentiable (or even continuous) to have a tangent line at a point.  So it's probably not a very useful definition.

There are generally two different ways of defining the tangent line in modern mathematics:

1. We just define it as the unique line which passes through the point on the curve and whose slope is the derivative of the curve at the point.  Note that the curve has to be differentiable at that point if its derivative exists.
2. We define the tangent line as the *best linear approximation* to the function at the point on the curve.  See professor Shifrin's  answer or [my answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784262/how-is-the-derivative-truly-literally-the-best-linear-approximation-near-a-po/1784280#1784280) for an explanation based on this definition.

Note that both of these definitions are equivalent.  Both require the curve to be differentiable at the point, will always identify a **unique** line (when it exists) tangent to the curve, and will always agree on which line that is.

Now, I did say that there are generally two ways of defining the tangent line, but there are some less often used geometrical definitions as well.  Michael Hardy gives a good one in his answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959885/is-there-a-geometrical-definition-of-a-tangent-line).

And thus the reason we would give as to why there's only one tangent line to a differentiable curve at a given point depends on how you define the tangent line to the curve.

Comment: Because as it turns out the best linear approximation *is* the line which passes through the point on the curve and whose slope is the derivative of the curve at the point.  Click the link entitled "my answer to this question" to see a derivation.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the derivative is unique (if it exists) because it is defined as a limit, and the value of a limit is unique. Indeed, if we assume that $c$ and $b$ are distinct and

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = c, \lim_{x\to a}f(x) = b$$
Then we can pick $\epsilon = \frac{|b-c|}{2}$, and so there exists $\delta$ so that $|x-a|<\delta$ implies both $|f(x) - b| < \epsilon$ and $|f(x) - c| < \epsilon$. But then
$$|b-c| = |b-f(x)+f(x)-c| \leq|b-f(x)|+|c-f(x)|<2\epsilon=|b-c|$$ 
Which is a contradiction. So, the value of a limit (and therefore the value of a derivative, if it exists) is unique.

Comment: Its not my answer.Read my qus carefully.

Answer (score 1):

But you have to consider the tangent of a singular point. The tangent only touches a specific singular point and does not touch the neighbour points. There is only a unique tangent which meets this condition. The picture below shows that only one straight line can touch the red point without touching one of the blue points. Any other straight line would touch or intersect one of the neighbour points. With some effort one can imagine this situation for infinitesimally small points.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean ?
 Please be more specific.

Comment: Read my question..

Comment: Read my answer. You have to consider one single point. Any other case doesn´t make sense. And don´t be so rude.

Comment: @callculus What about a line perpendicular to your given one?  It wouldn't touch any point on the curve (in this region) except the red one.  Really OP's (and your) idea of the tangent line as the unique line which only touches the curve once is full of problems.  See lulu's comment on the question.

Comment: @Bye_World It will intersect one of the points.

Comment: How?  Does the curve contain a cusp at that point?

Comment: @Bye_World It has one single point where the tangent touches one single point. That is what we do if $\Delta x \to 0$

Comment: Taking lulu's example, consider the curve given by $f(x)=x$.  Is there any way to restrict the interval around say the point $(1,1)$ such that the tangent line *only* passes through that point on the curve?  Now consider *any other line* through that point.  Will it pass through *any other point* on the curve $f(x)$?

Comment: Sorry, but you're just wrong.  This is not how we define the tangent line to a curve and your definition isn't even well-defined.

Comment: @Bye_World Sorry **I do not consider tangents for straight lines**. This doesn´t make sense.

Comment: OK.  Fine. That's crazy... but fine.  Consider the curve $f(x)=e^x$ at the point $(0,1)$.  The tangent line at that point is $g(x) = x+1$, do you agree?  Now consider the line $h(x) = -x+1$ (or even $h_1(x) = 1$).  This line *only intersects* the graph of $f(x)$ at the point $(0,1)$ but it is clearly **not** the tangent line to the graph.

Comment: @Bye_World In my answer I´m talking about **touching**, not intersecting. The purpose of the picture is to give a imagination of a tangent of a function.

Comment: "Touch" has no rigorous meaning in mathematics.  You're free to come up with your own definition of it if you like, but if you don't clearly define it, people will assume you mean "intersect" -- which does have a clear mathematical definition.  (Especially when your own answer states that "any other line would **touch or intersect** one of the neighbour points."  Which I've already demonstrated is false.)

Comment: @Bye_World I don´t know if it is really true that touching has no rigorous meaning in mathematic, but it is often used in school and university.

Comment: Teachers and professors use a lot of informal language to try to get students to understand the concepts.  You'll find that they do it less as you progress through your mathematical education, though.  Even taking the word "touch" informally in your answer, I still don't see any way in which this correctly explains why there is only one tangent line to any point on a differentiable curve.

Comment: @sani Oh, you are a child. In this case I have to forgive your rudeness for this time.

Comment: do u have any other option? @calu

Answer (score 0):

As @Ted Shifrin pointed, you define the derivative as the best linear approximation for the function in a point. In particular, when you refer to a real-valued function of real variable, which I assume is your concern from the description, you can speak about its *slope*.

That slope is the result of a limit, which, because of the properties of the topology in $\mathbb{R}$, must be unique. That means that if you assume there are two tangent lines for a curve in a single point then its derivative in the point cannot be defined, since the value of the limit will depend on how you approach the point.

Tangent lines are only (roughly speaking) equivalent to differentiation in differentiable functions.

Comment: I do not agree. When differentiation exists at any point. This means there exists a tangent at that point whose slope is equal to the differentiation.This is not saying that there will not exist any other tangent. There may be other tangent at that point whose slope is different from the differentiation value

Comment: Well than I'm afraid I must disagree with you on that - and we've turned a mathematics discussion into a philosophic one. If you define tangent as you did, that's the only answer you will ever get. Maybe you should be more explicit on what you understand by *tangent*.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a graph of a function, you can zoom in at the point in question further and further. For differentiable function, as your zoom factor grows to infinity, sooner or later the graph starts to appear more and more straight-like. The slope of this (almost) straight line is the value of derivative.

That means if you had a tangent line (tangent according to a common definition) at this point then eventually, as the zoom factor grows, you couldn't tell the two lines apart. This is a graphical way to say that derivative is the best linear approximation for the function at a given point (as it was said in another answer).

Now let's try to find another "tangent". Let's plot an "allegedly tangent" line with another slope through the point. As we zoom in, the graph of the function resembles the real tangent more and more. The "allegedly tangent" goes with different slope, so the two lines must intersect. The intersection angle may be small but it's not zero.

You may define "*touch*", redefine "*tangent*" and so on. **My point is: for differentiable function there is exactly one straight line you get while zooming in infinitely at a given point of the graph. As there is only one, it is somewhat special, therefore mathematicians have a specific term for it: the *tangent* at this point.**